# When did Internet Explorer add support for the for..in loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

If I remember correctly, older versions of Internet Explorer didn't support [the `for..in` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/55wb2d34%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

I've no idea which versions though, and it's not the easiest thing to Google.

According to Microsoft, it's supported in Quirks Mode, and in standards mode from IE 6 onwards:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/55wb2d34(v=vs.94).aspx ("Requirements" section near the bottom)

Which version of Internet Explorer added support for this?

Comment: There is quite a good site out there for this type of questions: http://caniuse.com

Comment: How old are you talking about? What versions of IE are you actually supporting?

Comment: @11684 That's where I went to answer this question.  Couldn't find for..in loops there, probably because they are an essential JS feature that's been around for so long.

Comment: @11684 caniuse only lists HTML5/CSS3 (ie - recent) stuff.

Comment: A little chart from MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/s4esdbwz(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: it is hard to see that , 20K+ reputation users asked such silly question rather then simply navigating mozilla javascript reference guide .

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar: of course, as a 6K user, it’s entirely understandable that you made a snarky comment about MDN instead of adding a link to whichever page on there answers the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can remember, *every* browser ever supporting JS has had to have support `for ... in` because until recently it was the *only* way to enumerate the keys of an object.

Comment: [MDN does indeed say it was in JavaScript 1.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Maybe I'm mis-remembering IE not supporting it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yes, I looked there too.  It's such a fundamental language construct that there's simply no way it was ever _not_ there.

Comment: this is JavaScript we're talking about. Developed in two weeks, I think?

Comment: (Prototyped in 10 days - http://brendaneich.com/2010/07/a-brief-history-of-javascript/, around the 5:00 mark.)

Comment: well, all I can say is, if I had a prototype language with unordered key value objects, the first thing I'd add would be `for ... in` ;-)

Comment: It's not often that *"As far as I can remember"* could be considered a suitable reference, but in this case I think it's more than enough. :)

Comment: yeah, well it is around 14 or 15 years since I first dabbled in JS.  I wish I had played with it much more in the meantime, I could have been _really_ good at it instead of merely "advanced" ;-)

Comment: Actually `for..in` was introduced in IE5... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: @Teemu: holy crap, I’ve only just noticed that you got the right answer, in a comment on the accepted answer. Copy your comment into an answer, and the acceptance points are yours.

Answer (score 3):

It is supported at least in IE6+. The for-in loop is in Ecmascript 3 which browsers have supported for a very long time. You should feel as comfortable using for-in as any other JS construct.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/s4esdbwz(v=vs.84)), the for...in statement was added in JScript version 5.0, which is used in Internet Explorer 5.0 .

JScript is Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript3. The prior link shows the products they use it, including old versions of Internet Explorer, Windows and VisualStudio.

Answer (score -1):

According to [microsoft official web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/for-dot-dot-dot-of-statement-javascript), here is what they say :

`for...of Statement (JavaScript)`
Not supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards, Internet Explorer 9 standards, Internet Explorer 10 standards, Internet Explorer 11 standards. Not supported in Windows 8.1.

Comment: That’s `for..of`; I was asking about [`for..in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/for-dot-dot-dot-in-statement-javascript).